# Calculated Column Will Not Show Up In Pivot Table Anymore

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, dax, calculated-columns

So, I had a Pivot Table with a CONCATENATEX calculated column in an .XLSX workbook.

Essentially, I am trying to create a comma delimited string with the CONCATENATEX DAX formula. The formula is: =CONCATENATEX(MediaLib,MediaLib[UNSPSC],","). The Measure Name is MediaLib_KeyString and the table name is MediaLib

It was working fine until I added data to the source table (in the same sheet and workbook). I add data to tables that are connected to Pivot tables all the time and this has never happened.

After "Refreshing All", I did not see the new data in the Pivot table.

I have tried copying and pasting special the data from that table into a new sheet and a new workbook then recreating the pivot table and that still does not get it to work.

When I check the formula it says that there are no errors and the green check mark shows up. It shows up in the PivotTable fields list. I can drag it into the Values section, but when I do nothing happens. It loads for a split second, but then the calculated column does not show up at all in the Pivot table.

I am assuming that I have some old formulas, references, relationships, or something that are getting in the way. I am not sure though. I have tried looking this up, but to no avail so I am not sure exactly what the issue is because Excel is not saying that there is an issue.

Also, I have deleted the table from the data model and re-inserted it. No luck there either. I have run Windows 10 updates, restarted computer, closed & re-opened with Task Manager, etc.

I am assuming that I will probably have to post the file here, but it is for work so I want to see if anyone has any recommendations or answers before posting it.

Here is a link to a sample file on my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fb9tCGdVRSo2P8XWt46fp24RNWjdrvIc/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

[Source Table with Pivot Table next to it and Field List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgPby.png)

[Measure Stays in Values But Nothing Happens in Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BumZO.png)

[Power Query Generated from Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fK4D.png)

Comment: UPDATE: When I check the "Defer Layout Update" box at the bottom of the Pivot Table Fields list, then the calculated column "stays" or "sticks", but nothing happens still. The calculated column will not "stay" in the Values section when that box is NOT checked.

Comment: @basodre if you could help or just share this that would be great. It hasn't gotten any attention in the last day so I thought I would reach out and see if you would be able to help. If not, I understand. If so, thank you! I will be doing this with other users who have helped me in the past.

Comment: Hello @Plentyofcoffee ! I posted this yesterday and it has not gotten any attention. Probably since I am a new user to this site. Anyways, if you could help or just share this then that would be a huge help. I posted it yesterday and it got no bites so I thought reaching out to some users who have helped me before would be a good next step.

Comment: Please create a [reprex], with the calculation for the column and sample data.

Comment: Hi @BigBen !!! Thank you for responding! Essentially, I am trying to create a comma delimited string with the CONCATENATEX DAX formula. The formula is: =CONCATENATEX(MediaLib,MediaLib[UNSPSC],",")............................the Measure Name is MediaLib_KeyString and the table name is MediaLib. I have used this formula numerous times before and it has suddenly stopped working. Also, I just tried to make a new Measure and it failed. It was a simple measure too. The formula was =LEN(MediaLib[UNSPSC]). I am not sure how to provide a better example without uploading the file somehow.

Comment: Here is my first attempt at a minimal reproducible example. Column 1 = "UNSPSC" and one value would be 39121521H. Column 2 = "UNSPSC_Count" and one value would be 6. Column 3 = "CategoryName" and one value would be Drywall Taping Tools. Column 4 = "Image_Count" and one value would be 6. Column 5 = "CatNameCount" and one value would be 1. Column 6 = "Divisions" and one value would be 51. Column 7 = "Groups" and this was a formula and then I copied and pasted the values. The formula was: ="MEDLIB" & @GETPIVOTDATA[Divisions]. A value of "Groups" is MEDLIB51. I am not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: If it doesn't help then I apologize. I honestly think it is an issue with some setting in Excel that only applies to my local machine. I thought I would be able to post something like this and then be able to post a file if necessary afterwards. I have an example file that I am willing to post.

Comment: Please [edit] the body of your question with the additional detail, instead of posting in comments. A screenshot might also be helpful. You can also include a link to the sample file on some file-sharing site (Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.).

Comment: No problem @BigBen. I am on it.

Comment: Hi @BigBen I added an image, the DAX Formula, and a Google Drive link to a sample file in the body of the question.

Comment: I'm not too strong in DAX but have a hunch that the problem may be related to this remark from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax?view=asallproducts-allversions): This function is not supported for use in DirectQuery mode when used in calculated columns or row-level security (RLS) rules. You may be able to achieve your end goal with Get and Transform (also known as Power Query).

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. I will try to use Power Query. I am not well versed with Power Query, but I will figure it out. Do you have any idea why this is just happening now? I never had to use Power Query for this scenario before.

Comment: As I mentioned, not too strong in DAX so my supposition may be entirely off.

Comment: Haha no problem @BigBen. I will let you know if I am able to get it to work with Power Query.

Comment: I don't think it worked @BigBen. I created a new query in the Power Query Editor from the original MediaLib table and then created a Pivot Table with the Measure from that query. The Measure still does not show up when I place it in the Values. BUT the Measure will stay in the Values section of I check off the "Defer Layout Update" checkbox. The Measure will be in the Values section, but nothing happens to the Pivot Table. See the added screenshots for more reference.

Comment: No you wouldn't use a Pivot Table for this, you would use the Transform functionality under Power Query.

Comment: Ok attempting to Transform in Power Query. I am grouping by Divisions, but then the Operation gets a bit hairy. I use MAX because when you Pivot in TSQL max is used to make the pivot contain the text within the pivoted columns. It did not work how I wanted so I tried editing the DAX formula to contain CONCATENATEX in it and that did not work either. I will mess around with it more and continue to research how to utilize CONCATENATEX in Power Query.

Comment: @BigBen I FINALLY got it to work with Power Query. I had to find some articles on how to edit the DAX. Essentially, I did a Group By in Power Query and changed the aggregated column from `List.Sum` to `Text.Combine` and that did the trick. I even added a second aggregate column as well as a custom column which were for some other measures I used to have in the Pivot Table. I am still concerned about why my Pivot Tables no longer allow me to display Calculated Columns (i.e. Measures), but for now my issue has been resolved. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Power Query was a great temporary fix. I performed a Group By and then changed the part of the DAX formula that referenced the aggregated column from `List.Sum` to `Text.Combine` then added the delimiter.

Although, the issue with the Pivot Table has since been resolved. For some reason, the Grand Totals needed to be removed, but *NOT* in the Design tab for the Pivot Table.

**I needed to right-click on the Pivot Table, select Pivot Table Options, Tables and Filters tabs, and uncheck both boxes in the Grand Totals section of that tab.**

It is odd because I thought of this and tried it before, but I only turned off the Grand Totals from within the Design tab and not the Pivot Table Options Window.

Apparently, there is a difference between doing this in the Design tab and the Pivot Table Options Window.